# MySQL ALTER TABLE add column: error at another column

Tags: mysql

ok, i have `people` table and try run sql-script with the next command:

```
ALTER TABLE `people`
    ADD COLUMN `name_spelling`
    VARCHAR(255) NULL DEFAULT NULL
    AFTER `last_name`;
```

Then I'll get a error:

```
[22001][1292] Data truncation: Incorrect date value:
'0000-00-00' for column 'birth_date' at row 35
```

At this row `birth_date` is `NULL`, but if I try set some date like `2016-05-05` at this column and row and than set `NULL` back -- all works is correct at this row, but get error on some next `null` date.

In addition, not all `null` date values return error.

Comment: Can you `describe` your table?

Comment: Does all other field of your database are nullable and are default values ? Cause if not nullable and not are defautl values... you will have this error on each filed.

Comment: @sisanared, `birth_date` created by `ALTER TABLE 'people' ADD COLUMN 'birth_date' DATE NULL  AFTER 'last_name';`

Answer (score 1):

Maybe your MySQL has some option such as the NO_ZERO_DATE SQL mode (I think it's not the only mysql config that prevents 0000-00-00 dates). This would prevent you from using 0000-00-00 as a value. It happened to me before that I had a table already created violating that condition. It will not be editable until you change the value or disable what's preventing you to set 0 dates.

For reference :http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/sql-mode.html

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this issue once and the fix i had was to to edit mysql.cnf file 
Replace : sql_mode='STRICT_TRANS_TABLES,NO_ZERO_IN_DATE,NO_ZERO_DATE,ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO,NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION'

with this :
sql_mode='STRICT_TRANS_TABLES,ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO,NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION'

Notice i removed the No_ZEROs in that options.