# How can I fix a spurious 1292 'Incorrect date value' error with MySQL?

Tags: php, mysql

I get the error when trying to add a text column to an existing MySQL table.

**The syntax I am using is:**

```
ALTER TABLE tbl_user ADD COLUMN vBio TEXT AFTER vFirstName;
```

How can I alter the SQL syntax to get rid of this **error**?

> ## 1292 - Incorrect date value ’0000-00-00’ for column ‘dDob’ at row 4

Comment: It's not quite a duplicate of that because I'm not trying to update a date, just to add a column.  I've tried SET sql_mode = ''; and that didn't work.

Comment: it works umpteenth times. Ensure that `set sql_mode = ''` is called in the same client session at the time of running `alter table` query. If you are using PHPMyAdmin, use both the queries together.

Comment: You're getting the error on another column instead of the one you're adding? Weird.

Comment: Indeed, it's a bit weird.

Comment: @SalmanA it is not weird. SQL modes have been made stricter since 5.7 ; Fixing the `0000-00-00` dates values should be the first choice.

Comment: Yeah... seems like it will ask you to fix the _other_ column before altering table... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40133392/mysql-alter-table-add-column-error-at-another-column

Comment: @MadhurBhaiya Running set sql_mode = '';ALTER TABLE tbl_user ADD COLUMN vBio TEXT AFTER vFirstName; in phpmyadmin as a single query did the trick like you say, many thanks.  The issue was I was trying to run the two as separate queries, hence why it didn't work.

Comment: @MichaelNares you should add that as the answer...then it's easy for others to search for in future. You are allowed to answer your own question (and accept your own answers), and others can vote for it then.

Comment: OK, well I can't really do that now that the answer has been closed, but hopefully people should be able to find this anyway.